# How can I debug a "Application Error" in my heroku hosted Ruby on Rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am getting a "Application Error" screen randomly during the day on my website that last up to 20 minutes.

When I use the basic logging module "heroku logs", it doesn't show any error as if the "Application Error" never occurred.

When I use the new logging module on Heroku, same thing.

GetExceptional doesn't report anything.

**How should I proceed to find what causes the error?**

Comment: Have you tried contacting support? If you can't access any logfiles, there might be something strange going on that's beyond your control - they could at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: It is not that I can't access the log files, it is that the log files are not reporting any error.

Comment: We also have the problem reported above. As an observation I would like to point out that "normally" when an app crash happens, the exception is captured by Airbrake and the 500 error page is rendered. In contrast to this behaviour, this heroku white-page Application error is not captured by airbrake and there is no insight from the logs.

Answer (score 16):

```
heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

should help. if not, you can use the free addon "exceptiontrap"

Comment: exceptiontrap is $9.00 on the cheapest plan

Answer (score 0):

You could install the [exception notifier](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification), which will send you an email for every `500` error including a full stack trace.

*OT: The basic heroku logs (= free version) are pretty useless IMO.*

Comment: I already use GetExceptional. Would the exception notifier report more errors?

Comment: I have no experience with GetExceptional, but after a quick look at their website I'd assume that they reports should be showing pretty much the same :/ — I guess you might have to get in touch with the Heroku support.